# How can I distribute weights knowing what's inside the box

Tags: algorithm, distribution

I have this problem and I think that I'm gonna need a mathematical solution.

I have some boxes. Of these, I only know their total weight and what is inside each one. I have to calculate each one's weight.

For example I have:

```
Total weight: 100
Number of boxes: 5
Number of items: 14

Stock:
Type1: 2 items
Type2: 1 items
Type3: 7 items
Type4: 4 items

Box #1: 
Type1: 2 items
Type2: 1 items

Box #2: 
Type4: 3 items

Box #3: 
Type3: 3 items

Box #4: 
Type3: 2 items
Type4: 1 items

Box #5: 
Type3: 2 items
```

Each box can potentially have n types of items, so how can I distribute the total weight?

I cannot divide the total weight by the number of boxes because the result would be equal for all boxes and this is not a real case.

Comment: Doesn't this belong to Mathoverflow? -edit- Anyway, @zmbq's looks like a good answer :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Didn't even know there's a math site, I apologize

Comment: @Phate01 That's ok, now you do :)

Answer (score 2):

You have:

- Four variables - the weight of each item type
- One linear equation `2A + B + 7C + 4D = 100` - what you know about the total weight.
- Some linear inequalities - you know that A, B, C and D are all positive.

There's an infinite number of possible solutions. For example A=B=C=2,D=20 or A=B=C=4,D=15 and everything in between.

Comment: Given that they could contain n different types of item, as in real cases there can be around 1000 total items, there isn't a way to calculate a proper weight for each box, right?